# how to find values from multiple conditions in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i'm trying to get column for `death` using value from `kill` column and how to achieve this by locating the `game_id` , `player` , `opponent`, `team` and `opponent_team`. My table look like this

| player | opponent | kill | team | opponent_team | map | game_id | match_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Laz | stax | 4 | ZETA | DRX | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| Dep | stax | 5 | ZETA | DRX | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| crow | stax | 1 | ZETA | DRX | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| SugarZ3ro | stax | 1 | ZETA | DRX | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| TENNN | stax | 4 | ZETA | DRX | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| Laz | MaKo | 1 | ZETA | DRX | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| Dep | MaKo | 2 | ZETA | DRX | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| crow | MaKo | 3 | ZETA | DRX | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| SugarZ3ro | MaKo | 1 | ZETA | DRX | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| TENNN | MaKo | 2 | ZETA | DRX | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| Laz | Zest | 2 | ZETA | DRX | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| Dep | Zest | 1 | ZETA | DRX | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| crow | Zest | 2 | ZETA | DRX | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| SugarZ3ro | Zest | 1 | ZETA | DRX | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| TENNN | Zest | 4 | ZETA | DRX | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| Laz | Foxy9 | 5 | ZETA | DRX | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| Dep | Foxy9 | 0 | ZETA | DRX | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| crow | Foxy9 | 2 | ZETA | DRX | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| SugarZ3ro | Foxy9 | 2 | ZETA | DRX | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| TENNN | Foxy9 | 2 | ZETA | DRX | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| Laz | Rb | 3 | ZETA | DRX | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| Dep | Rb | 2 | ZETA | DRX | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| crow | Rb | 0 | ZETA | DRX | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| SugarZ3ro | Rb | 2 | ZETA | DRX | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| TENNN | Rb | 3 | ZETA | DRX | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| stax | Laz | 1 | DRX | ZETA | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| MaKo | Laz | 2 | DRX | ZETA | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| Zest | Laz | 3 | DRX | ZETA | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| Foxy9 | Laz | 5 | DRX | ZETA | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| Rb | Laz | 6 | DRX | ZETA | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| stax | Dep | 3 | DRX | ZETA | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| MaKo | Dep | 3 | DRX | ZETA | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| Zest | Dep | 2 | DRX | ZETA | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| Foxy9 | Dep | 6 | DRX | ZETA | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| Rb | Dep | 1 | DRX | ZETA | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| stax | crow | 3 | DRX | ZETA | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| MaKo | crow | 1 | DRX | ZETA | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| Zest | crow | 4 | DRX | ZETA | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| Foxy9 | crow | 0 | DRX | ZETA | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| Rb | crow | 3 | DRX | ZETA | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| stax | SugarZ3ro | 2 | DRX | ZETA | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| MaKo | SugarZ3ro | 6 | DRX | ZETA | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| Zest | SugarZ3ro | 3 | DRX | ZETA | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| Foxy9 | SugarZ3ro | 3 | DRX | ZETA | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| Rb | SugarZ3ro | 4 | DRX | ZETA | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| stax | TENNN | 2 | DRX | ZETA | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| MaKo | TENNN | 3 | DRX | ZETA | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| Zest | TENNN | 3 | DRX | ZETA | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| Foxy9 | TENNN | 2 | DRX | ZETA | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| Rb | TENNN | 0 | DRX | ZETA | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |

and i need to transform into

| player | opponent | kill | death | team | opponent_team | map | game_id | match_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Laz | stax | 4 | 1 | ZETA | DRX | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| Dep | stax | 5 | 3 | ZETA | DRX | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| crow | stax | 1 | 3 | ZETA | DRX | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| SugarZ3ro | stax | 1 | 2 | ZETA | DRX | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| TENNN | stax | 4 | 2 | ZETA | DRX | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| Laz | MaKo | 1 | 2 | ZETA | DRX | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| Dep | MaKo | 2 | 3 | ZETA | DRX | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| crow | MaKo | 3 | 1 | ZETA | DRX | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| SugarZ3ro | MaKo | 1 | 6 | ZETA | DRX | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| TENNN | MaKo | 2 | 3 | ZETA | DRX | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| Laz | Zest | 2 | 3 | ZETA | DRX | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| Dep | Zest | 1 | 2 | ZETA | DRX | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| crow | Zest | 2 | 4 | ZETA | DRX | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| SugarZ3ro | Zest | 1 | 3 | ZETA | DRX | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| TENNN | Zest | 4 | 3 | ZETA | DRX | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| Laz | Foxy9 | 5 | 5 | ZETA | DRX | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| Dep | Foxy9 | 0 | 6 | ZETA | DRX | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| crow | Foxy9 | 2 | 0 | ZETA | DRX | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| SugarZ3ro | Foxy9 | 2 | 3 | ZETA | DRX | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| TENNN | Foxy9 | 2 | 2 | ZETA | DRX | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| Laz | Rb | 3 | 6 | ZETA | DRX | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| Dep | Rb | 2 | 1 | ZETA | DRX | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| crow | Rb | 0 | 3 | ZETA | DRX | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| SugarZ3ro | Rb | 2 | 4 | ZETA | DRX | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| TENNN | Rb | 3 | 0 | ZETA | DRX | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| stax | Laz | 1 | 4 | DRX | ZETA | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| MaKo | Laz | 2 | 1 | DRX | ZETA | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| Zest | Laz | 3 | 2 | DRX | ZETA | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| Foxy9 | Laz | 5 | 5 | DRX | ZETA | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| Rb | Laz | 6 | 3 | DRX | ZETA | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| stax | Dep | 3 | 5 | DRX | ZETA | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| MaKo | Dep | 3 | 2 | DRX | ZETA | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| Zest | Dep | 2 | 1 | DRX | ZETA | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| Foxy9 | Dep | 6 | 0 | DRX | ZETA | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| Rb | Dep | 1 | 2 | DRX | ZETA | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| stax | crow | 3 | 1 | DRX | ZETA | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| MaKo | crow | 1 | 3 | DRX | ZETA | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| Zest | crow | 4 | 2 | DRX | ZETA | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| Foxy9 | crow | 0 | 2 | DRX | ZETA | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| Rb | crow | 3 | 0 | DRX | ZETA | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| stax | SugarZ3ro | 2 | 1 | DRX | ZETA | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| MaKo | SugarZ3ro | 6 | 1 | DRX | ZETA | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| Zest | SugarZ3ro | 3 | 1 | DRX | ZETA | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| Foxy9 | SugarZ3ro | 3 | 2 | DRX | ZETA | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| Rb | SugarZ3ro | 4 | 2 | DRX | ZETA | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| stax | TENNN | 2 | 4 | DRX | ZETA | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| MaKo | TENNN | 3 | 2 | DRX | ZETA | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| Zest | TENNN | 3 | 4 | DRX | ZETA | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| Foxy9 | TENNN | 2 | 2 | DRX | ZETA | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |
| Rb | TENNN | 0 | 3 | DRX | ZETA | 1 Ascent | 119512 | 184456 |

I'm expecting to get `death` by using `kill` column as for the value from condition each `game_id` , `player` , `opponent`, `team` and `opponent_team`

Comment: It's not clear how you're getting this value. Can you explain some specific examples?

Comment: And reduce the size of your sample data, it's hard to see what's related when we have to scroll so much.

Comment: Everything has the same `game_id`.

Comment: Are you just trying to join each row with the row where `row1.player == row2.opponent`?

Comment: nah sir, it's needed @Barmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you need to perform a self-[`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) after swapping the team/opponent_team and player/opponent columns:

```
cols = ['team', 'opponent_team', 'game_id', 'match_id', 'player', 'opponent']

out = df.merge(df.rename(columns={'opponent_team': 'team', 'team': 'opponent_team',
                                  'player': 'opponent', 'opponent': 'player',
                                  'kill': 'death'})[cols+['death']],
               on=cols, how='left')
```

Output:

```
       player   opponent  kill  team opponent_team       map  game_id  match_id  death
0         Laz       stax     4  ZETA           DRX  1 Ascent   119512    184456      1
1         Dep       stax     5  ZETA           DRX  1 Ascent   119512    184456      3
2        crow       stax     1  ZETA           DRX  1 Ascent   119512    184456      3
3   SugarZ3ro       stax     1  ZETA           DRX  1 Ascent   119512    184456      2
4       TENNN       stax     4  ZETA           DRX  1 Ascent   119512    184456      2
5         Laz       MaKo     1  ZETA           DRX  1 Ascent   119512    184456      2
6         Dep       MaKo     2  ZETA           DRX  1 Ascent   119512    184456      3
7        crow       MaKo     3  ZETA           DRX  1 Ascent   119512    184456      1
8   SugarZ3ro       MaKo     1  ZETA           DRX  1 Ascent   119512    184456      6
9       TENNN       MaKo     2  ZETA           DRX  1 Ascent   119512    184456      3
10        Laz       Zest     2  ZETA           DRX  1 Ascent   119512    184456      3
11        Dep       Zest     1  ZETA           DRX  1 Ascent   119512    184456      2
12       crow       Zest     2  ZETA           DRX  1 Ascent   119512    184456      4
13  SugarZ3ro       Zest     1  ZETA           DRX  1 Ascent   119512    184456      3
14      TENNN       Zest     4  ZETA           DRX  1 Ascent   119512    184456      3
15        Laz      Foxy9     5  ZETA           DRX  1 Ascent   119512    184456      5
16        Dep      Foxy9     0  ZETA           DRX  1 Ascent   119512    184456      6
17       crow      Foxy9     2  ZETA           DRX  1 Ascent   119512    184456      0
18  SugarZ3ro      Foxy9     2  ZETA           DRX  1 Ascent   119512    184456      3
19      TENNN      Foxy9     2  ZETA           DRX  1 Ascent   119512    184456      2
20        Laz         Rb     3  ZETA           DRX  1 Ascent   119512    184456      6
21        Dep         Rb     2  ZETA           DRX  1 Ascent   119512    184456      1
22       crow         Rb     0  ZETA           DRX  1 Ascent   119512    184456      3
23  SugarZ3ro         Rb     2  ZETA           DRX  1 Ascent   119512    184456      4
24      TENNN         Rb     3  ZETA           DRX  1 Ascent   119512    184456      0
25       stax        Laz     1   DRX          ZETA  1 Ascent   119512    184456      4
26       MaKo        Laz     2   DRX          ZETA  1 Ascent   119512    184456      1
27       Zest        Laz     3   DRX          ZETA  1 Ascent   119512    184456      2
28      Foxy9        Laz     5   DRX          ZETA  1 Ascent   119512    184456      5
29         Rb        Laz     6   DRX          ZETA  1 Ascent   119512    184456      3
30       stax        Dep     3   DRX          ZETA  1 Ascent   119512    184456      5
31       MaKo        Dep     3   DRX          ZETA  1 Ascent   119512    184456      2
32       Zest        Dep     2   DRX          ZETA  1 Ascent   119512    184456      1
33      Foxy9        Dep     6   DRX          ZETA  1 Ascent   119512    184456      0
34         Rb        Dep     1   DRX          ZETA  1 Ascent   119512    184456      2
35       stax       crow     3   DRX          ZETA  1 Ascent   119512    184456      1
36       MaKo       crow     1   DRX          ZETA  1 Ascent   119512    184456      3
37       Zest       crow     4   DRX          ZETA  1 Ascent   119512    184456      2
38      Foxy9       crow     0   DRX          ZETA  1 Ascent   119512    184456      2
39         Rb       crow     3   DRX          ZETA  1 Ascent   119512    184456      0
40       stax  SugarZ3ro     2   DRX          ZETA  1 Ascent   119512    184456      1
41       MaKo  SugarZ3ro     6   DRX          ZETA  1 Ascent   119512    184456      1
42       Zest  SugarZ3ro     3   DRX          ZETA  1 Ascent   119512    184456      1
43      Foxy9  SugarZ3ro     3   DRX          ZETA  1 Ascent   119512    184456      2
44         Rb  SugarZ3ro     4   DRX          ZETA  1 Ascent   119512    184456      2
45       stax      TENNN     2   DRX          ZETA  1 Ascent   119512    184456      4
46       MaKo      TENNN     3   DRX          ZETA  1 Ascent   119512    184456      2
47       Zest      TENNN     3   DRX          ZETA  1 Ascent   119512    184456      4
48      Foxy9      TENNN     2   DRX          ZETA  1 Ascent   119512    184456      2
49         Rb      TENNN     0   DRX          ZETA  1 Ascent   119512    184456      3
```

Comment: thanks for advance , now i put player and opponent to finish the code